# PHP Put variable in SimpleXML

Tags: php, variables, simplexml

I have a problem with simpleXML and variable

```
$num = $categorie['id'];
echo $num; /*return value is 1 or 0*/
$fav = $xml->categorie[$num]->addChild("fav"," ");
```

I want to put $num in categorie[$num] but not work. How i can do this?

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
    <categorie id="0" name="Search">
        <fav>
            <link>Google</link>
            <desc>www.google.fr</desc>
        </fav>
        <fav>
            <link>Orange</link>
            <desc>www.orange.fr</desc>
        </fav>
    </categorie>
    <categorie id="1" name="Social">
        <fav>
            <link>Facebook</link>
            <desc>www.facebook.com</desc>
        </fav>
        <fav>
            <link>Youtube</link>
            <desc>www.youtube.com</desc>
        </fav>
     </categorie>
</data>
```

MY php complete php code. And the problem is in the foreach loop. i compare the categorie name to get the id and put the new favorite in the correct categorie.

```
<?php

$link = $_POST['link'];
$desc= $_POST['desc'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file('../data/data.xml');


foreach($xml->categorie as $categorie)
{
    if (strcmp($categorie['name'], $cat) == 0)
    {
        $num = $categorie['id'];
        echo $num;
        $fav = $xml->categorie[$num]->addChild("fav"," ");
        $fav->addChild("link", $link);
        $fav->addChild("desc", $desc);
        $xml->asXML('../data/data.xml');
    }
 }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post desired XML output. This will make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: We need to see at least a sample of the XML as well.

Comment: i edit my post with my php code and my xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert an object to integer with `intval()`

```
$num = intval($categorie['id']);
$fav = $xml->categorie[$num]->addChild("fav"," ");
$fav->addChild("link", $link);
$fav->addChild("desc", $desc);
$xml->asXML('../data/data.xml');
```